# How to continue the same video duration to other screen

Tags: android, android-videoview

Here I am going on with the fullscreen activity of playing video (i.e) i had two screens one is MainScreen and other one to view.In my FirstScreen I have several videos in listview if i longpress on the video it should take the video to Secondscreen there that patricular video should viewed in fullscreen.

If i am playing the video in Firstscreen with duration of(0:00 to 5:00 min) there my video is playing in duration (2:00 min)that time
if i longpress the video to view in fullscreen while video playing in Firstscreen with duration between (2:00 min)there the video should continue with the same duration in fullscreen.

I can able to send the video to other screen to view fullscreen video but my problem was it plays from the beginning of the video how can i continue the same duration(2:00 min) as in firstscreen tried a lot to do this but can't able to fix it.

If anyone have idea about this please help me friends.

Here is my code below:

**MainScreen:**

```
   public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                     videoPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    videoPreview.start();
                }

   videoFullScreenButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent videoIntent = new Intent(MainScreen.this, FullViewScreen.class);
               videoIntent.putExtra("current_position",videoPosition);
                startActivity(videoIntent);
      }
        });
```

**FullScreen:**

```
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                String id = intent.getStringExtra("current_position");


                mp.seekTo(Integer.parseInt(id));

                pDialog.dismiss();

                videoPreview.start();
            }
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"


    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/media_video_preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Debug your code. Is `videoPosition` proper while you put it in Intent? And try to check getIntent().getStringExtra(); in onCreate of FullScreen activity instead of onPrepare

Comment: but for me in the mainscreen itself the value didn't set for duration it set as 0

Comment: Because you are writing `videoPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();` onPrepare. Move it to `videoFullScreenButton`'s onClick's first line

Comment: let me check and rep u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `VideoView`, you can do this:

1. On LongPress event, capture the current position of video using [`getCurrentPosition`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.MediaPlayerControl.html#getCurrentPosition()) method:

   ```
   int videoPosition = mVideoView.getCurrentPosition();
   ```
2. Send this position along with video in Second Activity using `intent.putExtra()`
3. In your second activity, use [`seekTo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.MediaPlayerControl.html#seekTo(int)) to start the video from that particular position.

   ```
   mVideoView.seekTo(videoPosition);
   mVideoView.start();
   ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: let me try and know for u

Comment: after trying this i got null point error i have edited and posted my code can u plz see it and correct me where i go wrong

Comment: but for me in the mainscreen itself the value didn't set for duration it set as 0

Comment: what ever the postion of video

Comment: what ever the postion of video it set's as 0

Comment: how to get the play pause button option to center of the screen by default it shows at the bottom of the screen

Comment: @ MysticMagic how to get the play pause button option to center of the screen by default it shows at the bottom of the screen

Comment: @Manoj you will need to make changes in xml. If possible, show code or ask question with xml and give me link. Will try to help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27099882/how-to-get-hardware-key-option-to-center-of-screen

Comment: I had update the above and posted a question in stackoverflow added the link please see it

Comment: @ MysticMagic i had updated and posted a question please see it

Comment: i had posted question for background service can plz help me here is the link ;

Comment: i had posted question for background service can plz help me here is the link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27151744/how-to-stop-background-service-automatically-when-app-is-not-in-use

Comment: @ MysticMagic i had posted question for background service can plz help me here is the link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27151744/how-to-stop-background-service-automatically-when-app-is-not-in-use

Answer (score 0):

you can get current position of video onbutton click for full screen and set value to fullscreen activity and play from that position.

```
     public void fullscreen(){ 
     int current_position=mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
     Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, Fullscreen.class);
     i.putextra("value",current_position)
     startActivity(i);
       }
```

fullscreen activity

```
     Intent intent = getIntent();
     String id = intent.getStringExtra("value");

        mp.prepare();   
        mp.seekTo(Integer.parseInt(id)); 
        mp.start();
```

Comment: let me try it and know for u

Comment: duration= getIntent().getStringExtra("current_position");
    duration_time = Integer.parseInt(duration);
    videoPreview.seekTo(duration_time);  is this way of passing

Comment: String id where should i pass this id value

Comment: this is the track position where you left video before clicking fullscreen

Comment: what ever the duration it shows position as (0) and then id value set's as null,so it causes me null point error

Comment: @ raj can plz see my code and correct me where i go wrong

Comment: can plz see my code and correct me where i go wrong