# How to get hardware key option to center of screen

Tags: android, xml, android-mediaplayer

How to get the pause play forward button option to center of the screen in MediaPlayer but by default it shows at the bottom of the screen.

Here I am using videoView in fullscreen

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"


    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/media_video_preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

below i had updated my answer which i had tried and got solution for this please have look at it.

Comment: [May be you will need to use custom media controller](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3686729/1777090)

Comment: let me try and know for u

Comment: got it by mediaController.setPadding(0, 0, 0, px);

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom `MediaController` or set it position by

```
mediaController.setPadding(0, 0, 0, px);
```

[Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7040645/1777090)

You can also use `setAnchorView` which will reposition controller below particular anchor view, but in your case that won't be possible.

Hope this helps.

Comment: but for different resolution screen this padding is differ for each device

Comment: i had upadted the answer which i tried and got solution what i need please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

we can get key options any where in the fullscreen in videoview by below:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int screenWidthPx = (metrics.widthPixels);
     int screenHeightPx = (metrics.heightPixels);
 MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(Activity.this);
  mediaController.setPadding(0, 0, 0, screenHeightPx );
```

**screenHeightPx** : you can adjust it where ever you want in the screen.

Hope this helps.